# Not able to find abcissa of absolute convergence of this general dirichlet series

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series

I am reading about general dirichlet series from my class notes and I also referred to wikipedia here:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Dirichlet_series

In the 2nd section : Abcissa of convergence I am unable to follow with this: If $\sigma_{c} \leq 0$ then $\sum a_n$ converges. But how in this case $\sigma_{c} $ is given by $\sigma_{c} = lim n\to \infty sup \frac{ log |a_{n+1} + a_{n+2}+... | } {\lambda_{n}} $, which is clearly different from the case in which $\sigma_{c} \geq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

In this answer, we are going to prove

**Proposition:** Suppose the series $\sum_n a_ne^{-\lambda_ns}$ converges for some $s=s_0$ with $\sigma_0=\Re(s_0)<0$, then

$$
\limsup_{N\to\infty}{\log|a_N+a_{N+1}+\cdots|\over\lambda_N}\le\sigma_0
$$

*Proof.* For convenience, let's define

$$
A(x)=\sum_{n\le x}a_n
$$

and

$$
S(x)=\sum_{n\le x}a_ne^{-\lambda_n s_0}
$$

Then by the assumptions, we know that there exists $K>0$ such that $|S(x)|\le K$ holds for all positive $x$. Thus, if we let $N>M$ be two positive integers, then

$$
A(N)-A(M)=\sum_{M<n\le N}a_n=\sum_{M<n\le N}[S(n)-S(n-1)]e^{\lambda_n s_0}
$$

Now, it follows from summation by parts that

$$
A(N)-A(M)=S(N)e^{\lambda_Ns_0}-S(M)e^{\lambda_Ms_0}+\sum_{M\le n<N}S(n)[e^{\lambda_{n+1}s_0}-e^{\lambda_ns_0}]
$$

Now, by triangle's inequality, we have

$$
\begin{aligned}
|A(N)-A(M)|
&\le2Ke^{\lambda_M\sigma_0}+K\sum_{M\le n<N}|e^{\lambda_{n+1}s_0}-e^{\lambda_ns_0}| \cr
&\le2Ke^{\lambda_M\sigma_0}+K|s_0|\int_{\lambda_M}^{\lambda_N}e^{\sigma_0u}\mathrm du \cr
&\le K\left(2+\left|\frac{s_0}{\sigma_0}\right|\right)e^{\lambda_M\sigma_0}
\end{aligned}
$$

Since the resulting upper bound does not depend on $N$, we have that for each fixed $s_0$, there exists $B=B(s_0)>0$ such that

$$
|a_N+a_{N+1}+a_{N+2}+\cdots|\le Be^{\lambda_N\sigma_0}
$$

Taking logarithms on both side concludes the proof.

It can be easily shown that the limit supremum is exactly the abscissa of convergence. Hope this can address your concern!

Comment: But why in this case  $\sigma_{c} = lim n\to \infty sup \frac{ log |a_{n+1} + a_{n+2}+... | } {\lambda_{n}} $? and not $\sigma_{c} = lim n\to \infty sup \frac{ log |a_{1} + a_{2}+... + a_{n}| } {\lambda_{n}} $. I think your answer doesn't explains that

Comment: can you please reply to my above comment?

Comment: @Avenger you will always get zero using the second limit, so it will be reasonable to make the denominator go to infinity somehow. You might wish to have a glance at section 8.2 of Apostol's GTM41. The question you asked happened to be an exercise of that chapter.

Comment: Ya, I looked at that book, but it is an exercise not in theory. I think you should elaborate on the answer.

Comment: @Avenger General Dirichlet series is a special case of Laplace-Stieltjes transform, so you might find section II.1.1 of Ténenbaum's _Introduction to Analytic and Probabilistic Number Theory_ helpful.

Comment: I don't  have acess to this particular book. Actually, University is closed due to covid. If you have some time, can you please write a detailed answer?

Comment: @Avenger It's now updated. Please let me know if there are other concerns.